# What should be an Ideal git workflow if pull request not merged and upstream/master advances

Tags: git, rebase, pull-request

I want to understand what would be an ideal git workflow in case of open source projects where pull requests are submitted for new feature changes. I had this scenario (where M is the original upstream project and I forked the project at M2). I started working on the feature and added commits:

```
M1 --- M2 --- M3
       |
       M2 --- F1 --- F2
```

Now my feature was ready and I rebased my feature branch on top of M3 and submitted a Pull Request. So at this moment, my feature branch becomes:

```
M1 --- M2 --- M3 --- F1 --- F2
```

I pushed the above to my master and submitted a Pull Request. But my this PR didn't get merged. My PR was there for some days and master got advanced by this time.

```
M1 --- M2 --- M3 --- M4 --- M5
```

Now, the owner of the project after reviewing my changes asked me to submit a new PR with the latest changes. So at this state, if I again do a rebase on upstream/master with my feature branch checked out, will I not have this situation? :

```
(M1 --- M2 --- M3 --- M4 --- M5) --- (M1 --- M2 --- M3 --- F1 --- F2)
```

1) Is my thinking approach correct in understanding this git workflow?
2) What would be better or best practices to follow in such scenarios?

Please pardon me if this is the silliest question as I just started learning git and don't still learning most of the stuffs. Thanks!

Comment: are you releasing your changes in the master branch or in your branch? your work flow only merges changes into your branch. Use merges into master instead of rebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rebase again. A branch in git is just a pointer to a commit, so your situation is basically exactly the same as the one your had before you first rebased.

Keep in mind that your scenario looks like this currently:

```
  M1 --- M2 --- M3 --- M4 --- M5
                |
                M3 --- F1 --- F2
```

Which is very similar to what you had before. A rebase on master will result in:

```
M1 --- M2 --- M3 --- M4 --- M5 --- F1 --- F2
```

Comment: You can rebase as Many times as you want.... my only comment would be that M2 and M3 are duplicates on the charts you wrote.... that's not actually how it looks. There's a single M2 revision... so F1 points to M2... the same M2 that M3 points to in the first chart.... when you create your fork, the revision that the branch points to is M2 (M2 points to M2?). Anyway.

Comment: Im not familiar with the differences between rebase and merge, but I would re-merge the updated M5 branch back into the F1 branch and deal with any conflicts through negotiation with whomever controls the master.

Comment: @eftshift0 You're right, I just wanted to use the same syntax the OP was using so he could see how he's in the same situation now as before.